# TYPO3 - limit list view to first content element from page

Tags: php, typo3

We have made extension using Kickstarter. On DB we have lots of items with the same `pid` element. We would like to display on list, only first item based on `pid`. For example:

PID 1

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3

PID 2

- record 14
- record 15
- record 16

PID 3

- record 21
- record 22
- record 23

How to limit displayed items on list to only first elements: record1, record 14, record 21?

To select we use `pi_exec_query` function.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, really *old-school*, like it ;)

Anyway you should use [little bit younger API](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/47/html/classt3lib___d_b.html#a3e108e17834da69d638f3d9301f06628) for querying your tables:

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
    '*',
    'your_table',
    "pid=$myPid ",
    '',
    'uid ASC',
    '0,3' 
)
```

Comment: I know, I know... fluid extbase... But we are renegade of old-school :) I will try it and then I will give you info about our result